# NodeJS child_process.spawn stdout removes progress bar (stdio "inherit" is does not meet requirements)

Tags: node.js, stdout, updates, progress, spawn

**What I am doing:**
I made a API endpoint that executes `npx create-react-app projectname` via `NodeJS` `child_process` module `spawn` function. Which works perfectly.

Additionally I created another API endpoint that would `fetch` the `current progress` of the above API on demand. I've managed to get the `stdout` text from the `spawned child` and save it. I am returning the latest saved stdout when the API is called.

[Example of The stdout text used as progress updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiwXx.png)

(1) Creating a new React app in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeformula\build\myproject.

(2) Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

(3) Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

The point #3 above takes roughly 5 minutes to complete, and in the terminal it has a nice `progress bar`.

**What I am trying to achieve**
I'd like to get my hand on that `progress bar` and convert it to a `% value` so that I can display the % value along with the text.
[To clarify what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/240P9.png)

**The issue:**
It seems like the `progress bar` is being delivered through `another stream` as it displays when using `{stdio:"inherit"}` as a spawn option, but I cannot intercept, manipulate, and store the progress bar % (or rather I dont know if it is possible to intercept stdio: "inherit").
[The progress bar I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqWbz.png)

**What I've Tried:**
I've tried using `exec`, `spawn` with `pipe`, `wrapped callback functions`, `child.stdout.on` and `child.stderr.on` and the progress bar seems to be stripped from these methods. I am out of ideas and looking for answers or some inspiration or another method to achieve the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbuffer` from the `expect` package to make the child process think that it is outputting to a 'normal' terminal:

```
const process = spawn('unbuffer', ['npx', 'create-react-app', 'projectname'])
process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  // Handle stdout data
}
```